# Should this question be marked as 'Primarily Opinion Based'

Tags: discussion

This question that I'm concerned about is [Is it a bad thing to create views programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436913/is-it-a-bad-thing-to-create-views-programmatically).

From the gist of it, it appears that OP has created views programmatically and is now realizes that it could've been easier if OP had used AutoLayout. Changing the question to 'How to make programmatically created views adjust for different devices' would be too big a change and against OP's intent (although might prove useful)

Comment: Yes. The answers on there are opinion-based.

Comment: I became really concerned because the question has received upvotes and is getting upvotes even now. Glad that I was right about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I started answering this question and realised I was using phrases like:

> I favour...

and

> I would probably..

So I stopped answering and voted to close.